# check words with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have some words with `|` between each one and I have tried to use `preg_match` to detect if it's containing target word or not.

I have used this:

```
<?php

$c_words = 'od|lom|pod|dyk'; 
$my_word = 'od';  // only od not pod or other word


if (preg_match('/$my_word/', $c_words))
{
echo 'ok';
}

?>
```

But it doesn't work correctly.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regular expressions. The functions [`explode($delimiter, $str);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`in_array($needle, $haystack);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will do everything for you.

```
// splits words into an array
$array = explode('|', $c_words);

// check if "$my_word" exists in the array.
if(in_array($my_word, $array)) {
    // YEP
} else {
    // NOPE
}
```

---

Apart from that, your regular expression would match other words containing the same sequence too.

```
preg_match('/my/', 'myword|anotherword'); // true
preg_match('/another/', 'myword|anotherword'); // true
```

That's exactly why you shouldn't use regular expressions in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a variable into a string with single quotes, you need to use either

```
preg_match("/$my_word/", $c_words);
```

Or – and I find that cleaner :

```
preg_match('/' .$my_word. '/', $c_words);
```

But for something as simple as that I don't even know if I'd use a Regex, a simple `if (strpos($c_words, $my_word) !== 0)` should be enough.

Comment: `strpos('od', 'lom|pod')` would match so that's not an option. Same goes for your regular expression.

Comment: On the other hand we have no idea what $c_words is ? Was that meant to be `$all_words` ?

Comment: He probably meant `$my_word` instead

Comment: @TimS. you are right strpos('od', 'lom|pod') would match so that's not an option

Answer (score 0):

You are using `preg_match()` the wrong way. Since you're using `|` as a delimiter you can try this:

```
if (preg_match('/'.$all_words.'/', $my_word, $c_words))
{
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Read the [documentation for `preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).